# how to calculate $[T(v)]_B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $B=\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$  and $B'=\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$ be the bases for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let $A=\begin{bmatrix}2 &-2 \\-1 &3 \end{bmatrix}$, be the matrix of $T:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ relative to $B$.

$(a)$ Find the transition matrix $P$ from $B'$ to $B$,

$(b)$ Use the transition matrices $P$ and $A$  to find $[v]_B$  and $[T(v)]_B$  where$[v]_{B'}=(-1 \ \ 4)^T$.

**Answer

$(a)$,   $T(x,y)=A \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \end{bmatrix}=(2x-2y,-x+3y).$

$T((1,0))=(2,2)=2(1,0)+2(0,1) \\ T((1,1))=(0,2)=0(1,0)+2(0,2).$

Then the transition matrix $P=\begin{bmatrix}2 &0 \\ 2 &2 \end{bmatrix}$   from $B'$ to$B$.

$(b)$ Now,

$[v]_B=P*[v]_{B'}=\begin{bmatrix}2 &0 \\ 2 &2 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-2 \\ 2 \end{bmatrix}$.

But how to calculate $[T(v)]_B$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution given is wrong. The transition matrix $P$ is $[{\rm Id}]_{B',B}$ and it is not related to any linear operator whatsoever. For some weird reason, people always have trouble finding matrices of linear operators when the algorithm is very simple:

1. apply the operator in the elements of the first basis;
2. write the results as combinations of the vectors in the second basis;
3. put the coefficients of the combinations found in the previous item in columns.

Thus, to find $P$, we apply the identity mapping to $(1,0)$ and $(1,1)$, write the results (themselves) as combinations of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, and put the coefficients in columns (the coefficients are the entries of the vectors in the first basis, without any change, because the second basis is the standard one). So $$P = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Thus $$[v]_{B} = [{\rm Id}]_{B',B}[v]_{B'} = P[v]_{B'} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} -1 \\ 4\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 4\end{pmatrix}.$$
Now, we know that $A = [T]_B$. And $$[T(v)]_B = [T]_B[v]_B = A[v]_B = \begin{pmatrix}2 & -2 \\ 1 & 4 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}3 \\ 4 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 19\end{pmatrix}.$$